# How to reverse ALT + LEFT MOUSE and CTRL + LEFT MOUSE bindings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In sublime text CTRL + LM adds a cursor and feels much more natural than ALT + LM, because I keep accidentally clicking the space bar and inserting a space.

I also like the VSC CTRL + LM file path peek option, but I just want to reverse the two buttons.

So inserts cursor should be: CTRL + LM

And peek path should be: ALT + LM

I can't find them anywhere in the key bindings shortcuts. Where are these two settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no possibility to customize any of the mouse related functionality in VS Code.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3130), though, that you can "thumbs up" and follow.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I really hope they are able to add this.